# Configure NGINX in docker container to network with other docker container app

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have one docker container with nginx (path docker/nginx):

```
services:

  web:
      image: nginx
      volumes:
           - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      ports:
           - "80:80"
      networks:
           - nginx-net

networks:
        nginx-net:
           name: proxynet
           external: true
```

And docker with app (docker/app):

```
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app_php
    networks:      
      - nginx-net   

networks:
  nginx-net:
    external: true
    name: proxynet
```

File nginx conf.template

```
 server {
      listen 80 default_server;
     server_name subdomain.domain.com;
  
  
          location /{
    proxy_pass app_php:80/; 
    }
}
```

I want nginx to redirect to the app container and to other containers in the future.

But in web browser subdomain.domain.com show 504 error.

`ping -c 4 app_php`  - ping from nginx container is ok

I spent a few hours and I don't know what the problem is, I suspect nginx conf

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose app_php on another port eg. 8000 and have nginx act as proxy for that. Something like:

```
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app_php
    networks:      
      - nginx-net
    ports:
      - 8000:80
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;

    location /{
          proxy_pass http://app_php:8000; 
    }
 }
```

Probably best to have all containers in a single docker-compose.yml file also.

Comment: Everything in one docker-compose is better, but if I have several such containers with different applications on one host listening on port 80, there will be no problem?  Of course, each application is a separate domain.

Comment: Each container will need to be exposed on a different port eg. 8000, 8001, 8002 etc. Then nginx will need to reverse proxy each of those ports with different fully qualified domain names for each.

Comment: I don't think the line `proxy_pass app_php:8000;` works; you need an `http://` or `https://` prefix, otherwise you get `invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/conf.d/yoursitehere.conf`

Comment: I have amended the line to include http://